# Race condition and interleaving when Struclog logger is used within Celery tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, structlog

I use `structlog` and `celery` in my Django application and I'm having hard time when logging tasks with structlog in the console. Indeed, events are not properly aligned when printed in the console when a Celery task is being executed.

How can I fix the misalignment ?

### EDIT

As you can, there is interleaving in the console when printing [Task Events](https://django-structlog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#celerymiddleware) from `django-structlog`. Same thing happen if I print the logs from the applications.

**Console**

```
$ docker-compose logs -f


celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:11.064644Z [info     ] task_enqueued                  [django_structlog.celery.receivers] child_task_id=edad4137-4b9b-4f80-b335-65b9728afcc2 task_id=edad4137-4b9b-4f80-b335-65b9728afcc2
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:15.224614Z [info     ] task_enqueued                  [django_structlog.celery.receivers] child_task_id=c2fa7030-7583-467f-96fa-0ff04b238cd7 child_task_name=Account______Fetch orders ip=178.238.xxx.ppp request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=3ee2d948-c179-43b4-8ec9-18e5a4d93327 user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:15.304021Z [info     ] task_enqueued                  [django_structlog.celery.receivers] child_task_id=f5db5a8d-d9fc-4238-b701-aefbf7412d08 child_task_name=Account______Fetch orders ip=178.238.xxx.ppp request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=3ee2d948-c179-43b4-8ec9-18e5a4d93327 user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:15.343569Z [info     ] task_succeeded                 [django_structlog.celery.receivers] ip=178.238.xxx.ppp request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=3ee2d948-c179-43b4-8ec9-18e5a4d93327 user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:17.036935Z [info     ] task_enqueued                  [django_structlog.celery.receivers] child_task_id2022-10-14T15:21:17.039814Z=bfdbad61-5a09-41a1-b96d-1fe13c8b6cf0 child_task_name=PnL_____Update_asset_inventory ip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id=f5db5a8d-d9fc-4238-b701-aefbf7412d08 request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=c5c6a3d8-d371-45c5-bc15-d555c40c9fe7 user_id=1
celery_worker-1  |  [info     ] task_enqueued                  [django_structlog.celery.receivers] child_task_id=c5c6a3d8-d371-45c5-bc15-d555c40c9fe7 child_task_name=PnL_____Update_inventories ip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id=3ee2d948-c179-43b4-8ec9-18e5a4d93327 request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=f5db5a8d-d9fc-4238-b701-aefbf7412d08 user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:17.058236Z2022-10-14T15:21:17.059109Z [info     ] task_enqueued                  [django_structlog.celery.receivers] child_task_id=92a94e61-0d86-4e12-be02-e54fda559df3  [info     child_task_name] =task_succeeded                PnL_____Update_contract_inventory [ django_structlog.celery.receivers] ipip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id==178.238.xxx.ppp f5db5a8d-d9fc-4238-b701-aefbf7412d08parent_task_id =request_id3ee2d948-c179-43b4-8ec9-18e5a4d93327 request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=f5db5a8d-d9fc-4238-b701-aefbf7412d08= 03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41user_id =task_id1
celery_worker-1  | =c5c6a3d8-d371-45c5-bc15-d555c40c9fe7 user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:17.077882Z [info     ] task_succeeded                 [django_structlog.celery.receivers] ip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id=f5db5a8d-d9fc-4238-b701-aefbf7412d08 request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=c5c6a3d8-d371-45c5-bc15-d555c40c9fe7 user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:17.149324Z [info     ] task_succeeded                 [django_structlog.celery.receivers] ip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id=c5c6a3d8-d371-45c5-bc15-d555c40c9fe7 request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=92a94e61-0d86-4e12-be02-e54fda559df3 user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:17.171073Z [info     ] task_succeeded                 [django_structlog.celery.receivers] ip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id=c5c6a3d8-d371-45c5-bc15-d555c40c9fe7 request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=bfdbad61-5a09-41a1-b96d-1fe13c8b6cf0 user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:18.477145Z [info     2022-10-14T15:21:18.478784Z] task_enqueued                  [django_structlog.celery.receivers] child_task_id=99175fd3-12c7-4354-bdce-60dce014b888 child_task_name=PnL_____Update_asset_inventory ip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id=c2fa7030-7583-467f-96fa-0ff04b238cd7 request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=9fc68b47-4c56-44bc-a5c1-5df1062c98ef user_id=1
celery_worker-1  |  [info     ] task_enqueued                  [django_structlog.celery.receivers] child_task_id=9fc68b47-4c56-44bc-a5c1-5df1062c98ef child_task_name=PnL_____Update_inventories ip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id=3ee2d948-c179-43b4-8ec9-18e5a4d93327 request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=c2fa7030-7583-467f-96fa-0ff04b238cd7 user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:18.504804Z2022-10-14T15:21:18.505474Z [info     ] task_succeeded                 [django_structlog.celery.receivers] ip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id=3ee2d948-c179-43b4-8ec9-18e5a4d93327 request_id [=info     03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=c2fa7030-7583-467f-96fa-0ff04b238cd7 user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | ] task_enqueued                  [django_structlog.celery.receivers] child_task_id=27211ff3-15df-4d2f-a040-a4d7acf7441f child_task_name=PnL_____Update_contract_inventory ip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id=c2fa7030-7583-467f-96fa-0ff04b238cd7 request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=9fc68b47-4c56-44bc-a5c1-5df1062c98ef user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:18.541556Z [info     ] task_succeeded                 [django_structlog.celery.receivers] ip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id=c2fa7030-7583-467f-96fa-0ff04b238cd7 request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=9fc68b47-4c56-44bc-a5c1-5df1062c98ef user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:18.581544Z [info     ] task_succeeded                 [django_structlog.celery.receivers] ip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id=9fc68b47-4c56-44bc-a5c1-5df1062c98ef request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=99175fd3-12c7-4354-bdce-60dce014b888 user_id=1
celery_worker-1  | 2022-10-14T15:21:18.620567Z [info     ] task_succeeded                 [django_structlog.celery.receivers] ip=178.238.xxx.ppp parent_task_id=9fc68b47-4c56-44bc-a5c1-5df1062c98ef request_id=03a1f3ec-4a96-4bac-831f-630b9881fd41 task_id=27211ff3-15df-4d2f-a040-a4d7acf7441f user_id=1
```

**Packages version**

```
celery==5.2.7  # latest
django-structlog==3.0.1  # latest
structlog==22.1.0  # latest
```

**tasks.py**

```
import structlog

logger = structlog.get_logger(__name__)


@app.task(bind=True, name='Update_inventory')
def update_inventory(self, pk):

    account = Account.objects.get(pk=pk)
    log_asset = logger.bind(account=account.name)
    log_asset.info('Log event')
    ...
```

**celery.py**

```
import structlog
from django_structlog.celery.steps import DjangoStructLogInitStep

app.steps['worker'].add(DjangoStructLogInitStep)


@setup_logging.connect
def receiver_setup_logging(loglevel, logfile, format, colorize, **kwargs):  # pragma: no cover
    logging.config.dictConfig(
        {
            "version": 1,
            "disable_existing_loggers": False,
            "formatters": {
                "json_formatter": {
                    "()": structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
                    "processor": structlog.processors.JSONRenderer(),
                    "foreign_pre_chain": [
                        structlog.contextvars.merge_contextvars,
                        structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt="iso"),
                        structlog.stdlib.add_logger_name,
                        structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
                        structlog.stdlib.PositionalArgumentsFormatter(),
                    ],
                },
                "plain_console": {
                    "()": structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
                    "processor": structlog.dev.ConsoleRenderer(),
                },
                "key_value": {
                    "()": structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
                    "processor": structlog.processors.KeyValueRenderer(
                        key_order=['timestamp', 'level', 'event', 'logger']),
                },
            },
            "handlers": {
                "console": {
                    "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                    "formatter": "plain_console",
                },
                "json_file": {
                    "class": "logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler",
                    "filename": "logs/json.log",
                    "formatter": "json_formatter",
                },
                "flat_line_file": {
                    "class": "logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler",
                    "filename": "logs/flat_line.log",
                    "formatter": "key_value",
                },
            },
            "loggers": 
                "django_structlog": {
                    "handlers": ["console", "flat_line_file", "json_file"],
                    "level": "INFO",
                    'propagate': False
                },
            }
        }
    )

    structlog.configure(
        processors=[
            structlog.contextvars.merge_contextvars,
            structlog.stdlib.filter_by_level,
            structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt="iso"),
            structlog.stdlib.add_logger_name,
            structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
            structlog.stdlib.PositionalArgumentsFormatter(),
            structlog.processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
            structlog.processors.format_exc_info,
            structlog.processors.UnicodeDecoder(),
            structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter.wrap_for_formatter,
        ],
        logger_factory=structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
        cache_logger_on_first_use=True,
    )
```

**settings.py**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'json_formatter': {
            '()': structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
            'processor': structlog.processors.JSONRenderer(sort_keys=False),
        },
        'plain_console': {
            '()': structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
            'processor': structlog.dev.ConsoleRenderer(pad_event=43, colors=True, force_colors=True),
        },
        'key_value': {
            '()': structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter,
            'processor': structlog.processors.KeyValueRenderer(key_order=['level',
                                                                          'logger',
                                                                          'event',
                                                                          'timestamp'],
                                                               sort_keys=False
                                                               ),
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'plain_console',
        },
        'json_file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/json.log',
            'formatter': 'json_formatter',
        },
        'flat_line_file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/flat_line.log',
            'formatter': 'key_value',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django-structlog': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'flat_line_file', 'json_file'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': False,
        }
    }
}

structlog.configure(
    processors=[
        structlog.contextvars.merge_contextvars,
        structlog.stdlib.filter_by_level,
        structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt="iso"),
        structlog.stdlib.add_logger_name,
        structlog.stdlib.add_log_level,
        structlog.stdlib.PositionalArgumentsFormatter(),
        structlog.processors.StackInfoRenderer(),
        structlog.processors.format_exc_info,
        structlog.processors.UnicodeDecoder(),
        structlog.stdlib.ProcessorFormatter.wrap_for_formatter,
    ],
    logger_factory=structlog.stdlib.LoggerFactory(),
    cache_logger_on_first_use=True,
)
```

Comment: I've already had a long answer written, but let's take it slowly. Firstly and most importantly: structlog is a red herring here. What you have there is a race condition between `logging` handlers that write at the same time – long after structlog handed off the log entry. Your entries aren't misaligned, they are **interleaved**. Could it be that Django and Celery are competing here?

Comment: I just remembered [this issue](https://github.com/hynek/structlog/issues/287): it seems like Celery would you like to use its own `get_task_logger()` within tasks. Would you mind checking https://github.com/hynek/structlog/issues/287#issuecomment-990648826 if this helps?

Comment: oh, and have you seen / applied https://django-structlog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/celery.html ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I can  finally put words on the issue: "race condition" and "interleaving". In regard to your questions, yes I followed the upgrade recommendation from the `django-structlog` package. For the Github discussion, I think it's related to another problem which is the have `structlog.getLogger()` working in a Celery task in replacement of the Celery logger which doesn't support structured logs natively.

Comment: Now, if I understand the issue correctly there is no solution other than limiting the elements printed in the console, For example by removing some of the elements like the logger name, the timestamp or the log level.

Comment: My understanding from the issue is that django-structlog's features aside it should work if you your `logger = structlog.wrap_logger(celery.utils.log.get_task_logger(__name__))` – would you mind trying that? I'm currently working on the docs and consider adding a Celery recipe. I suspect Celery's logger takes care of the race condition.

Comment: @hynek I did the test by wrapping the Celery logger but unfortunnatly it doesn't log anything in the console. Not sure what is the reason.

Comment: I don't see any Celery output in your question, could it be, that you haven't configured the Celery logger (standard library logging is relevant here).

Comment: @hynek I'm confused, aren't logs output from `docker-compose logs -f` Celery output ?

Comment: No it's not. It's output from your Celery tasks, but you've configured your own `logging.StreamHandler` for output. I think Celery want you to use their own logger that will prevent your problems. Suggestion: check out https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#logging and try to get output from `get_task_logger` w/o structlog and *then* let's add another moving part. (just to stress: you would have the same problems without structlog. there's some intricacies in integration, but your current setup is independently broken ;))

Comment: @hynek hi, I checked the Celery logger and found it didn't printed logs because of the loggers configuration. Indeed, an empty key `"": {}` was absent from the dictionary but it seems necessary. For some reason, when I comment this key and create another key with the name of my applications it has no effet. It is weird. I did the test with all the application `"":{}` and only for the `django-structlog` app which logs Task Events from the middleware. Unfortunnatly, result is that both tests failed to fix the interleaving issue. Please see the edit with logs output and the configuration. Thanks